# Index pathing dates for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollection view where I want to take todays date and place it into the first cell then have 4 more cells with the next 4 days.

I am trying to figure out the right code to use for indexing these 5 days.

Here is the code I have:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 5

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = dateCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dateCell", for: indexPath) as! DateCell

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "E"
    let weekday = formatter.string(from: Date())
    print(weekday)
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd"
    let day = formatter.string(from: Date())

    cell.day.text = String(weekday)
    cell.date.text = day

    return cell

}
```

This displays the same date in all 5 cells.

If I try to use `let weekday = formatter.string(from: Date()[indexPath.row)]

I get the error:

> Type 'Date' has no subscript members

How would I indexpath the date so that each cell contains the next day similar to a calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your data into an array. Then your data source methods can use the array to provide the data they need.

Add a property to your view controller:

```
var dates = [Date]()
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`, populate the array with your dates.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // any other code you need

    // populate array
    let today = Date()
    dates.append(today)
    for days in 1...4 {
        let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: days, to: today)!
        dates.append(date)
    }
}
```

Then update your data source methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dates.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = dateCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dateCell", for: indexPath) as! DateCell

    let date = dates[indexPath.row]

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "E"
    let weekday = formatter.string(from: date)

    formatter.dateFormat = "dd"
    let day = formatter.string(from: date)

    cell.day.text = "\(weekday)"
    cell.date.text = day

    return cell
}
```

By doing this you don't need to hardcode the count or specific dates in the data source methods. If you want different dates, simply update the code in `viewDidLoad` to put whatever dates you want into the array.